# Is is possible to suppress the automatic time stamp in an Ant property file?

Tags: ant, netbeans-7

When I compile my project in Netbeans, I want to automatically generate a file that includes  a build number that automatically increments and date, so I added the following to my projects build.xml file.

```
<target name="-pre-jar" >
    <propertyfile file="${src.dir}\buildstring.txt" >
        <entry key="devbuild" value="1" type="int" operation="+"/>
        <entry key="devbuildtime" type="date" value="now" pattern="yyyy MM dd hh_mm" />
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

When the Ant task executes, Ant automatically adds a date stamp as the first line of the file

```
#Tue, 12 Jun 2012 16:09:24 -0500
devbuild=8
devbuildtime=2012 06 12 04_09
```

Is there any way to stop Ant from automatically adding the first line with the date comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PropertyFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) Ant task is implemented using a [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object. The `Properties.store()` method is documented with the following note:

> Next, a comment line is always written, consisting of an ASCII # character, the current date and time (as if produced by the toString method of Date for the current time), and a line separator as generated by the Writer.

Therefore, the date comment cannot be disabled using the `PropertyFile` task. Removing the date comment would require a different solution, such as post-processing the properties file or writing the properties file using a different technique (for example, using an Ant script or custom Ant task).

See: [Remove comments in properties file java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058638/remove-comments-in-properties-file-java)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up up using the property file to keep track of the auto increment build number only. I added a second task that reads the build number from the file property file and then use ECHO to create a buildstring.txt file without a comment. A little tedious, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:
1. write the properties in a temp file
2. copy the temp file to the final property file using `filterchain` to skip the first line
3. delete the temp file

```
<propertyfile file="temp.properties" >
    <entry  key="property.1" value="value1"/>
    <entry  key="property.2" value="value2"/>
</propertyfile>

<copy file="temp.properties" tofile="final.properties">
  <filterchain>
      <headfilter skip="1"/>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
<delete file="temp.properties"/>
```

Comment: I ran the code above (only in my case I do it within the `-ivy-retrieve` target) . I get: "Error cannot find the web pages folder. Open the project properties file and in the Sources category browse the correct Web Pages folder." And in the log: "cannot build classfiles for source directories". And it deletes my "Web Pages" and "Source Packages" folders. Any idea what's going on?